# mail server administration

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, postfix, smtp

MY postfix does not show that it  is listening to the  smtp daemon getting mesaage below:

The message WAS NOT relayed 
Reporting-MTA: dns; mail.mak.ac.ug
Received-From-MTA: smtp; mail.mak.ac.ug ([127.0.0.1])
Arrival-Date: Wed, 19 May 2010 12:45:20 +0300 (EAT)

Original-Recipient: rfc822;dicts-test@muklists.mak.ac.ug
Final-Recipient: rfc822;dicts-test@muklists.mak.ac.ug
Action: failed
Status: 5.4.0
Remote-MTA: dns; 127.0.0.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.4.0 Error: too many hops
Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 19 May 2010 12:45:20 +0300 (EAT)
Final-Log-ID: 23434-08/A38QHg8z+0r7
 undeliverable mail MTA BLOCKED

OUTPUT FROM lsof -i tcp:25 command

master  3014 root   12u  IPv4   9429       TCP *:smtp (LISTEN) (Postfix as  a user is missing )

Answer (score 1):

Your postfix is it the final hop for muklists.mak.ac.ug ?
Check your DNS entries for this domain. Is there an error ?

I think postfix say "Hey it's not for me, I send to muklists.mak.ac.ug. Who is muklists.mak.ac.ug ? 127.0.0.1 say DNS or /etc/hosts. Then it is send to 127.0.0.1, which say Hey it's not for me"

You can maybe check your logs too : you should see a large loop, because hopcount_limit is 50 by default

Comment: Double check MX record of mail.mak.ac.ug. 
you have to do it within linux box terminal & a third party dns resolver like intodns.com or checkdns.net 

http://www.intodns.com/mak.ac.ug